# Boost asio - multiple streambufs or one per connection?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using Boost asio to send and receive framed TCP messages. Does anyone know the correct way to use a streambuf?

Should I receive into one streambuf per connection, and parse the messages out to pass around in my application?

Or can I read into a single streambuf per message, and pass the streambufs themselves around?

Ideally I'd like an easy way of parsing individual data fields into/out of a message, such as using an istream/ostream.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't want to pass the buffers around, you would want to deserialize the content into some form of internal message which is easier to pass around. You may want to investigate something like Google's protocol buffers or boost serialization etc. to allow you to send real messages over the wire.

Typically you'd want to use a buffer per connection, in the read handler deserialize the message, and reuse the buffer for the next read.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming I need seperate buffers for send/receive?